# Wordpress: White space below footer

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I got a problem with 2 out of 4 webpages on my WP site.

I got a whitespace below my footer. I've tried with position: fixed; and bottom: 0;.. But its not working.

Im kind of stuck right now.

PHP Code

```
<?php
/* Template Name: Contact_page */
get_header(); /* HÄMTA HEADER */
?>

<?php
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'employe', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
?>      

<section class="contact_section"> 

        <article>
        <?php the_content(); ?> 
        <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>   
        </article>
 </section> 
 <?php
 endwhile;
 ?>

<?php
get_footer(); /* HÄMTA FOOTER */
?>
```

Here is the css code for the  contact page

```
.contact_section{
margin: auto;
max-width: 60%;
margin-top: 40px;   
}


.contact_section article {
margin-top: 20px; 
width: 60%;
margin:auto;
}

.contact_section p {
float: left;
font-size: 1.8em;
}

.contact_section img{
margin-left: 20px;
}
```

CSS for footer

```
footer {
clear: both;
text-align: center;
bottom: 0;

background-color: #444444;
height: 200px;
padding-top: 30px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some fiddle or working example?

Comment: Show us live link where you are facing issue so we can help.

Comment: http://webso.se/wordpress/kontakt/

Kontakt and Referenser is the pages with the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to position the footer to `absolute` and give the body tag a padding of 200px at the bottom, like this:

```
body {
  /* 200px for the footer and 30px for the padding body */
  padding-bottom: 230px;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 200px;
}
```